# Ejabberd error while communicating Wait for feature request error

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

```
2016-09-05 19:34:51.079 [info] <0.498.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.3947>}
2016-09-05 19:35:06.894 [info] <0.491.0>@ejabberd_listener299 (#Port<0.3948>) Accepted connection 103.255.4.61:40738 -> 162.243.172.244:5222
2016-09-05 19:35:07.306 [info] <0.500.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_feature_request:789 ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.3948>,<0.499.0>}) Failed authentication for 57a6697147e6e21b268b456d@server1.**.com from 193.355.4.61
2016-09-05 19:35:08.225 [info] <0.491.0>@ejabberd_listener299 (#Port<0.3949>) Accepted connection 103.255.4.61:40739 -> 162.243.172.244:5222
2016-09-05 19:35:08.503 [info] <0.502.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_feature_request:789 ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.3949>,<0.501.0>}) Failed authentication for 57a6697147e6e21b268b456d@server1.**.com from 193.355.4.61
```

Getting this error when XMPP-master client app try to send Request to Driver app

Comment: Error says explicitly authentication is failing.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: @MickaëlRémond yes, but I can't figure that out at which point this error is occurs. Can you help me out, I'm new to XMPP and ejabberd. When I try my API in the browser, value goes to MySQL successfully. When same API I tried from the android app, i'm getting that auth error in the log. So what you suggest ??